# Click en "Solve Captcha" de Buster: Captcha Solver en Selenium Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, captcha

he instalado la extensión [Buster: Captcha Solver for Humans](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/buster-captcha-solver-for/mpbjkejclgfgadiemmefgebjfooflfhl) y quiero hacer que haga click en el botón para resolverlo, he probado con todo pero me dice que no lo encuentra, aun habiendo pues la xpath.

```
captcha_click = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/form/div[6]").click()
time.sleep(3)
solve = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div/div/div[7]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[6]/button").click()
driver.implicitly_wait(5)  # esperamos a que la pagina haya cargado
frame = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//iframe[contains(@src, "recaptcha")]')  # buscamos el iframe del reCaptcha
driver.switch_to.frame(frame)  # selecionamos el iframe
captcha = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='recaptcha-anchor']")  # definimos "captcha" como el objeto final
value = captcha.get_attribute("aria-checked")  # comprobamos el valor actual de aria-checked
print("Aria-Checked: {}".format(value))  # Aqui imprimos el valor actual, el resultado seria false
import selenium.webdriver.support.ui as ui  # importamos ui si no está importado

wait = ui.WebDriverWait(driver, timeout=120)

confirmar = wait.until(captchaCheck)
```

Este es el error que me da:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"/html/body/div/div/div[7]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[6]/button"}
  (Session info: chrome=80.0.3987.149)
```

Comment: Quieres dar click al rectángulo del captcha?

Comment: Quiero darle click al simbolo de resolver el captcha de Buster

Comment: Prueba utilizando buscador por XPath hacia `//*[@id="solver-button"]`

Comment: ya lo intenté pero me sale que no se ha podido encontrar

Comment: Eso es debido, a que el elemento se añade a la página cuando encuentra un captcha y no está incluido en el código fuente del sitio. El driver busca coincidencias en el código html al cargar la página y eso resulta en no poder encontrarlo

Comment: Entonces no hay manera de ubicarlo con xpath, no?

Comment: Como andas... No hay posibilidad de que uses pyautogui para ese paso?

Comment: @yaom1ng nop, estuve mirando y nada. Opte por darle yo mismo. Pones `sleep.time(30)` mas o menos dependiendo de tu habilidad para darle y tu internet, si detras de esto hay un comando de encontrar algo en la web el programa espera hasta que se termine de cargar la pagina, me explico. Si en esos 30 segundos haces el captcha y cambias de pagina/se actualiza el programa espera hasta que la pagina cargue por completo asi que no pasa nada si mientras carga la pagina se acaba el tiempo

Answer (score 0):

`>WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"iframe[title^ ='recaptcha challenge']")))
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="solver-button"]'))).click()` 1. Elemento de lista

De poco te va a servir, porque google detecta de que es un bot y te bloquea el captcha audio. ¿Alguien sabe como hacer este comando en javascript?

Comment: Una explicación con la respuesta no estaría mal por tu parte.